# SQLITE: Display difference between three table difference with two condition

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have 2 tables naming labels5,labels.

[image]

i would like to compare the difference between this two column data and display.

same like below i need it in sqlite query.

[image]

current codings.

```js
public Cursor getLotsPerCustomer1(long name) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  String whereclause = KEY_NAME + "=?";
  String[] whereargs = new String[] {
    String.valueOf(name)
  };
  return db.query(TABLE_LABELS, null, whereclause, whereargs, null, null, ROUTE);
}
```

i want same as below in sqlite format. please advise.

```js
select t1.route from labels t1
left
join labels5 t2 on t1.route = t2.number
where t2.number is null
```

There is two condition is involved.

**First condition is check the table "customer" and search the matching result from table labels which is working fine this query.**

```js
public Cursor getLotsPerCustomer1(long name) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  String whereclause = KEY_NAME + "=?";
  String[] whereargs = new String[] {
    String.valueOf(name)
  };
  return db.query(TABLE_LABELS, null, whereclause, whereargs, null, null, ROUTE);
}
```

**Second condition is ,
After passing the first condition then it should also compare with table "labels5" thats where i struck** .Appreciate your advise.

TABLE CUSTOMER:

```js
CREATE TABLE "customer" (
  "_id"
  TEXT,
  "customer_name"
  TEXT
);
```

TABLE LABELS

```js
CREATE TABLE "labels" (
 "sno" INTEGER,
 "route" TEXT,
 "id" TEXT,
 "_id" TEXT
);
```

TABLE LABELS5

```js
CREATE TABLE "labels5" (
 "id3" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
 "number" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 "outletname" TEXT,
 "sunday" INTEGER,
 "monday" INTEGER,
 "tuesday" INTEGER,
 "wednesday" INTEGER,
 "thursday" INTEGER,
 "saturday" INTEGER,
 "closed" INTEGER,
 "calling" TEXT,
 "week" INTEGER
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by difference? IDs in one table but not the other?

Comment: yes your correct

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `rawQuery()`:

```
public Cursor getRoutes(long name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select t1.route from labels t1 left join labels5 t2 on t1.route = t2.number where t2.number is null";
    return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```

Comment: your query is somewhat similar but some changes. Please check my updated information and advise accordingly

Answer (score 0):

A better way to get the values from one table that aren't in another is to use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT route FROM labels
EXCEPT
SELECT number FROM labels5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
select customer_name as FirstTable,route as SecondTale,number as ThirdTable

from customer,labels,labels5
where customer._id=labels._id AND labels.route=labels5.number
```

Comment: this gives only what i created i need it in reverse way